# Storyboard Designtime Layout Attributes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

This is a feature a like a lot when defining layouts for Android and that allows to define attributes just to design.

http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes

But I didn't find any equivalent way to do the same when using storyboard to make iOS Apps.

At the moment I a cleaning all the design values on a viewDidLoad of my ViewController. Is there a way to define layout attributes as design placeholders and avoid making this setupClean step in all my view controllers?

Comment: I think you just described [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/) in the Interface Builder

Comment: [This book](https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Autolayout-Xcode-Steven-Lipton-ebook/dp/B0187YL9UA) was a huge help for me understand and use Auto Layout.

Comment: No, I don't mean auto layout. AFAIK there is no way to define a text in a UILabel in Design time using autolayout

Answer (score 3):

When You want Instant Reflect of attributes/properties of particular componet in storyboard then you can achieve using **@IBDesignable**.

To achieve this You have to **subcalss** of that type of which you want to be reflected on storyboard.

**Steps**

1. Make a subclass of the type you want be reflected on storyboard, as in example here i am going to subclass **UILabel** as **DGlabel**
2. Make that calss as **@IBDesignable**, see the example
3. Assign that subclassed to the component from **Identity Inspector**, see screen shot [image]
4. In subclassed calss (here in example **DGLabel**) declare variables of properties/attributes which you want be reflected on design as **@IBInspectable**, see example here i have decalred **borderColor** as **@IBInspectable**, this means this property will be listed on property inspector of Xcode

now you can change the value of that property from story board as screen shot below

[image]

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class DGLabel: UILabel {

@IBInspectable var borderColor:UIColor = UIColor.red {
    didSet {
        reflectChange()
    }
}

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}

func reflectChange() {

    self.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
        }

}
```

Hope this will allow you to understand the process.

Comment: But in this example it will set the border with as 1 even in runtime and the questions it's to see only in storyboard editor and not when running the app

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that by providing runtime attribute in "User defined runtime attributes" section under storyboard's Identity inspector. See below screenshot for setting UILabel's "text" keypath's runtime value as blank.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve something similar by using `IBDesignable` for your views. Then you may use `prepareForInterfaceBuilder()` and `TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER` to generate mock data for display in Interface Builder.

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean this?

[image]

You can change Label Text value in storyboard from the "Attribute Inspector".

Comment: No, that is the real value. The UILabel will take this value in runtime. What I am looking for is for a text that I can configure in the Storyboard, to design, but that will not be applied to the UILabel itself when the app runs

Comment: then set the value in your code like label.text = @"your text"